# Can you stretch a function with a zero or undefined gradient?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, transformation

If $y=f(x)$ is either $y=3$ (zero gradient) or $x=2$ (undefined gradient), is it possible to stretch $y=f(x)$ by graphing $y=af(x)$ or $y=f(ax)$?
If it is possible to stretch them, can you only stretch them parallel to one of the axes or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the equations you mention don't describe a function, but they do describe a set of points in the plane.

It is always permissible to replace $y$ by $y/a$ or $x$ by $x/b$ (for nonzero $a$ and $b$) in the defining equations to produce vertical or horizontal scaling of the point set, with the caveat that any limitations on $x$ or $y$ in the original set of equations may need to be adjusted appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but I'm still a bit confused (I'm pretty novis at maths). Could you please re-phrase your answer in layman's terms, or walk through how you could transform a line f(x)=3 or f(y)=3 into lines with gradients that aren't zero or undefined?

Comment: If the slope is zero or undefined, then the stretched versions will also have slope zero or undefined. It's because if you stretch a rectangle vertically or horizontally, you still have vertical and horizontal lines, just different lengths. You can't change the slopes in this case. You would be stretching directly away from (or towards) one of the axes. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes a lot more sense.